# How i can perform request to tarantool like in mysql?

Tags: tarantool

I need select from tarantool all datat by two values from one space.
How i can perform request to tarantool like in mysql?

```
select from aaa where a=1a22cadbdb or a=7f626e0123
```

Now i can make two requests:

```
box.space.logs:select({'1a22cadbdb'})
box.space.logs:select({'7f626e0123'})
```

but i don't know how to merge result into one ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code merge field[0] to lua table

```
a = box.space.logs:select({'1a22cadbdb'})
b = box.space.logs:select({'7f626e0123'})
c = { field_1 = a[0], field_2 = b[0] }
```

The select return tuple or tuples so you can extract value via [].

More details about select: http://tarantool.org/doc/book/box/box_index.html?highlight=select#lua-function.index_object.select

More details about tuple: http://tarantool.org/doc/book/box/box_tuple.html?highlight=tuple#lua-module.box.tuple

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays Tarantool allows you to retrieve via SQL, for example box.execute([[select from "aaa" where "a"='1a22cadbdb' or "a"='7f626e0123';]]). You have to add the field names and types of aaa before doing this, with the format() function.

Answer (score 0):

For me this work fine, but need make check for return from first select:

```
local res = {}
for k, v in pairs (box.space.email:select({email})[1]) do
    if type(v) == 'string' then
        table.insert(res, box.space.logs:select({v})[1])
    end
end
```