# Reference Search in Tarantool

Tags: tarantool

I have two tables: **user**, **user_matching**. And I wanna get items from both tables in 1 query. For example, SQL-like query:

```
select * from user where user.id = (select id from user_matching where id = user_matching_id)
```

Usually I should use 2 query in NoSQL DB. Now I do it like this:

1. Get from **user_matching** user_id
2. With user_id Get from **user**

Can I replace it with only 1 query using Tarantool. And How To?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create stored procedure where you combine result of two selection, e.g.:

```
function select_user_by_matching_id(matching_id)
    local id = box.space.user_matching:get{matching_id} # or :select
    local user_data = box.space.user:get{id} # or :select
    # work with user_data
    return user_data
end
```

After you create this procedure you can call this procedure via Tarantool driver with fetching combined result.

More detail here: http://tarantool.org/doc/book/app/c-lua_tutorial.html?highlight=call

Comment: But how to combine tuples from 'id' & 'user_data' into one tuple?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177960/how-i-can-perform-request-to-tarantool-like-in-mysql/36178380#36178380 here you will find answer